# Command to trigger a mousewheel event

Tags: wpf, command, mousewheel

I am doing a research of Kinect to browse pictures.

My application has the ability to change pictures by sending command `System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{Right}")`.  Now to enlarge the picture, I want to trigger the mousewheel event.

How to write the code just like  `{System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{Right}"); }` for the right key? Another method would be also appreciated.

Comment: What language are you using?  (Please add tag)

Comment: I am sorry, i know little about english and this is my first time to use stackoverflow.If you can resove my question,please do help.